# Run all code within a page consecutively in C# (Using Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I have values from controls `txtUser` and `txtAppNum` on a page webform1.aspx. I am bringing those values to a page, `Login.aspx`. The code from Login.aspx is below. In the `login.aspx` page, I want to take the values from the controls `txtUser`and `txtAppNum` in `webform1.aspx` page, I want to check the values against a database, if the values are in the database, I want the page to redirect back to `webform1.aspx`.

My questions is, when I run the code, only `Page_Load` but not `CheckRecord`. Basically when I run the page, I can see the values carried over from the `webform1.aspx` page to `login.aspx`, but then that's it, nothing else happens.

What am I doing wrong? Any thoughts, I would greatly appreciate it, I have been stuck on this for a few days. Thanks!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient; //to communicate with the Server database
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data; //to use DataSet or DataTable
using System.Text; //for StringBuilder

namespace BLAA_3
{
    public partial class login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Page PreviousPage = Page.PreviousPage;
            if (PreviousPage != null)
            {
                lblUserLogin.Text = ((TextBox)PreviousPage.FindControl("txtUser")).Text;
                lblAppLogin.Text = ((TextBox)PreviousPage.FindControl("txtAppNum")).Text;

            }

            {

                string _connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            }
        }


        public void CheckRecord(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //get the connection
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ServerInfo"))
            {
                //write the sql statement to execute
                string sql = "select username FROM BLAA_users WHERE username = @username";

                //instantiate the command object to fire
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
                {
                    //attatch the parameter to pass, if no parameter is in the sql no need to attatch
                    SqlParameter[] prms = new SqlParameter[1];
                    prms[0] = new SqlParameter("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                    prms[0].Value = lblUserLogin.Text.Trim();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(prms);
                    conn.Open();
                    object obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                    conn.Close();
                    if (obj != null)
                    {
                        Response.Redirect("~/WebForm1.aspx");
                    }
                    else
                        Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
                }

        }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that calls `CheckRecord`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `CheckRecord` an event handler?  If not, you don't need the `sender` and `eventArgs` in your signature for `CheckRecord` it can be  `public void CheckRecord()`.

It's not being called because your load event isn't calling it.  So, inside your `Page_Load` function.

```
    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page PreviousPage = Page.PreviousPage;
        if (PreviousPage != null)
        {
            lblUserLogin.Text = ((TextBox)PreviousPage.FindControl("txtUser")).Text;
            lblAppLogin.Text = ((TextBox)PreviousPage.FindControl("txtAppNum")).Text;

        }

        {

            string _connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        }

        CheckRecord();
    }

    public void CheckRecord()
    {
        //get the connection
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ServerInfo"))
        {
            //write the sql statement to execute
            string sql = "select username FROM BLAA_users WHERE username = @username";

            //instantiate the command object to fire
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
            {
                //attatch the parameter to pass, if no parameter is in the sql no need to attatch
                SqlParameter[] prms = new SqlParameter[1];
                prms[0] = new SqlParameter("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                prms[0].Value = lblUserLogin.Text.Trim();
                cmd.Parameters.AddRange(prms);
                conn.Open();
                object obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                conn.Close();
                if (obj != null)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("~/WebForm1.aspx");
                }
                else
                    Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
            }

        }

    }
```